# What is gcc make process doing?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

So I I've downloaded gcc-7.1.0 source archive from the gcc ftp server and I've configured it like this:

```
../configure --enable-languages=c --disable-multilib
```

As the sub-directory is where I've extracted the source. The current directory is named 'objdir'.

Now if I run `make -j 2` after like 5 mins initially and now for like 1 ~ 2 when I only modify single source file in the project - the `CC1` which is essentially what we are compiling is created/updated in `objdir/gcc` with about 110MB in total size - a totally working driver which I can use/debug etc. But then after like 3 or 4 seconds this files is moved into `objdir/prev-gcc` and then I've waited no more than lets say 20min.

I think I'll continue killing the make process after the `prev-gcc` directory is created and work with what's there but I'm wondering what is the reason for this quirk. Like what is the reason for the make process to move the totally working compiled binaries to `objdir/prev-gcc` and then continue doing something seemingly very (I remember waiting whole day to complete once) long or am I missing something obvious here.

Comment: Run `make -j2 bootstrap` and don't interrupt/kill the process.  This builds the compiler in three stages — the first uses the bootstrap compiler to build GCC; the second uses the GCC that was just built to build GCC again; the third builds GCC yet again, making sure that the result is the same.  On a MacBook Pro (15", 2016), I use `make -j8 bootstrap` and the entire process (3 phases) took just over an hour.  That's with SSD rather than spinning disks.  It shouldn't take all day unless you've got a very antiquated machine.  Can you afford to use `-j4` or `-j8`?

Comment: Also note the [install instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html): _First, we highly recommend that GCC be built into a separate directory from the sources which does not reside within the source tree. This is how we generally build GCC; building where srcdir == objdir should still work, but doesn’t get extensive testing; building where objdir is a subdirectory of srcdir is unsupported._  You are building with _objdir_ as a subdirectory of _srcdir_ — according to the docs, your build is unsupported.

Comment: With the source in `…/gcc-7.1.0`, I create `…/gcc-7.1.0-obj`, then use `cd …/gcc-7.1.0-obj; ../gcc-7.1.0/configure …` and `make -j8 bootstrap`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have 2 cores - stable at 2400 Mhz kept currently at around +44.0 C degree Celsius and I feel the full process is taking too long. But whatever you said that on some MacBook is taking over an hour so my definition of long I guess is not relevant in the case. Thanks for the extensive info though.

Comment: My machine has _Processor Name: Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 2.7 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Memory: 16 GB_  I'd guess you should look for it to take a couple of hours — 4 tops — unless you have very slow disks.  (If you have very little spare disk space, that could be a factor.  IIRC, the full build, source plus object, takes a couple of GiB, though 7.1.0 is smaller than 6.3.0 because it doesn't have the Java compiler any more.)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to disable the normal gcc 3-stage bootstrapping process (rebuilding the compiler with itself to test things), use `--disable-bootstrap` as an option to configure.  This will configure the Makefile to just build gcc once.

As for what the default (bootstrap) process is doing:

- compile gcc with the system compiler to create the "stage1" compiler
- recompile everything with the stage1 compiler to produce the stage2 compiler
- recompile everything with the stage2 compiler to produce the stage3 compiler
- compares the stage2 and stage3 compiler (binaries) to ensure that they are identical.

If that last check fails, then something went wrong with the build process.